# Setup cakephp in subfolder on AWS

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I had shifted my cakephp website to a subfolder on AWS ubuntu machine. Site is working but CSS, Images and JS are not loading. 
I am getting 404 not found error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /demo/css/mscrollar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css was not found on this server.
```

Urls are working only with index.php.

Here is the htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /demo
 RewriteRule ^media/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/files/timthumb.php?src=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/app/webroot/files/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two htaccess files. One in the webroot and one in the root path. 
The one in the root (./.htaccess) should look like this (replace YOUR_PATH):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /YOUR_PATH
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The one in the webroot folder (./app/webroot/.htaccess) should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```